# why isn't box-shadow not shown on left side of floated divs if they have background css property

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple markup:

**HTML**

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    float:left;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 58px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #A6BFE1;
    font: 14px/42px Open Sans;
    color: #FFF;
}

div:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

However, when hovered, the box-shadow is not shown on the right side of a div - please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WW5f/) - hover over 2nd div to see. Why isn't it shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later floats are positioned "over" earlier floats (see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) where it says "Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order."). This causes the float on the right to obscure the right side of the box shadow of the float on the left when it's hovered.

A trivial workaround for this is to cause a div to be positioned only when hovered:

```
div:hover {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

This ensures that [it and its box shadow will be painted on top of any surrounding floating divs](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9WW5f/3).

Answer (score 0):

It's because right shadow is below other divs. Using some `z-index` will reveal right side shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/9WW5f/1/